# How can I check when a mentioned user reacts?

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to check when a certain user reacts, but I'm not sure how.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed(
  )
  embed.add_field(name="⌛ Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member}.")
  offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
  await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
  await member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
  await asyncio.sleep(30)
  await offer_sent.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

unrelated to to topic of this post, but when using asyncio.sleep it is in seconds not minutes meaning that the offer would only last 30 seconds.

You should change it to `await asyncio.sleep(1800)`.

1800 seconds is 30 minutes

Comment: I know that hence why I said 'unrelated to to topic of this post'

Comment: I think it's better to add those as comments.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can add a `@client.event` decorator *outside* the `offer` command. Just like:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="⌛ Incoming Offer", value=f"The 
        <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member}.")
    offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
    await member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. 
        You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
    await asyncio.sleep(1800) # Replace "30" with 1800, because 1800 in seconds is 30 min.
    await offer_sent.delete()
 
# Reaction detector:

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    reaction1 = "<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>"
    reaction2 = "<a:XMark:768095331555606528>"
    if reaction.emoji in [reaction1, reaction2]:
        # Do anything after the user reacted
        await reaction.message.channel.id.send(f'{user} reacted with {reaction}!')
```

Comment: Nope, I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't respond.

Comment: Also, would posting the event outside of the `offer` command still allow it to detect the reaction from the command?

Comment: Yes, it would still work to detect reactions in the command. It's just going to be a global detection, and not just for when someone runs that command.

Comment: Oh alright, I tried adding it to the string because I wasn't sure. The command is fine for me now. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's alright! Also, make sure that you don't have any error handlers that hide the errors. At least add `print(error)` at the end of each error handling code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226198/discussion-between-toohard-and-ggberry).